# Are rifts different if you open them in different acts?

Tags: diablo-iii

In the new expansion, does it matter which act you are in when you open a rift? Does it change anything if you open a rift in a different act?

Comment: Was my answer helpfull ? If so don't forget to tick it so future user can know, if not don't hesistate to tell me what was wrong with it so I can edit it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nephalem rifts are a randomized dungeons system. It doesn't matter where you open the rift or the difficuly in which you open it, the place of the rift and the number of level is decided at random.

[From the Diablo Wikia](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Nephalem_Rift)

> The layouts stem from taking the tilesets and dungeons of the game and
>   re-organizing/shuffling them. Monsters are likewise re-shuffled, found
>   in combinations otherwise not present. The rifts have 1-10 levels.
>   Each level is effectively a different dungeon, with a different
>   monster combination.[4] They are accessed via Nephalem Obelisks.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the difficulty of the game in which the rift is open has no effect on the rift. Can you confirm this? In my limited experience, the difficulty matches that of the game.

Comment: The difficulty match your difficulty level selectionned, only the level and the number of level you can explore is randomized.